# I do not know what to put as a parameter in order to assign value to a variable

Tags: python, variables, functional-programming, global-variables

I right now have them set as global but I do not know how to set up the argument and parameters in order to save the variable bmr in order to use it in another function such as get_calorie_requirement. I know i have a lot of inputs in order to get the bmr. Should I define the formula get_bmr? I am stuck on something simple because I am trying to do bmr= get_bmr(bmr) but that is wrong.

```
import math
def get_bmr():    
    gender = input("What is your gender: M or F?")
    age = int(input("What is your age?"))
    height = int(input("What is your height in inches?"))
    weight = (int(input("What is your weight in pounds?")))
    bmr_wght_constant = 4.536
    bmr_hght_constant = 15.88
    bmr_age_constant = 5
    if gender == 'M':
        bmr = int((bmr_wght_constant * weight) + (bmr_hght_constant * height) - (bmr_age_constant * age) + 5)
    elif gender == 'F':
        bmr = int((bmr_wght_constant * weight) + (bmr_hght_constant * height) - (bmr_age_constant * age) - 161)
    else:
        print("Please try again.")
    return bmr

def get_daily_calorie_requirement():
    dcr_1 = 1.2
    dcr_2 = 1.375
    dcr_3 = 1.55
    dcr_4 = 1.725
    dcr_5 = 1.9
    act_lvl = int(input("What is your activity level?"))
    if act_lvl == 1:
        daily_calorie_requirement = int(bmr * dcr_1)
    elif act_lvl == 2:
        daily_calorie_requirement = int(bmr * dcr_2)
    elif act_lvl == 3:
        daily_calorie_requirement = int(bmr * dcr_3)
    elif act_lvl == 4:
        daily_calorie_requirement = int(bmr * dcr_4)
    elif act_lvl == 5:
        daily_calorie_requirement = int(bmr * dcr_5)
    else:
        print("Please choose a number 1-5.")
    return daily_calorie_requirement
def main():
    print("Hello, welcome to my intergration project!")
    print("The purpose of this program is to help the user reach their goal and provide helpful suggestions.")
    print("It will do this by taking your age, gender, height and your level of physical activity in order to calculate your Basal Metabolic Rate(BMR)")
    print("Your BMR is how many calories you burn in a single day. Combining your BMR with your goals we can suggest a meal plan and excercises that will help reach your goals")
    print("Let's get started! I will start by asking you a few questions in order to make a profile and give you the best informed advice.")      
    if gender == 'M':
        bmr = int((bmr_wght_constant * weight) + (bmr_hght_constant * height) - (bmr_age_constant * age) + 5)
    elif gender == 'F':
        bmr = int((bmr_wght_constant * weight) + (bmr_hght_constant * height) - (bmr_age_constant * age) - 161)
    else:
        print("Please try again.")
    print("Your BMR is: ", bmr)

    print("Great! Now that we have calculated your Basal Metabolic Rate, let's calculate your daily calorie requirement!")
    print("This is the calories you should be taking in to maintain your current weight")
    print("How active are you on a scale of 1-5?")
    print("1 being  you are sedentary (little to no exercise)")
    print("2 being lightly active (light exercise or sports 1-3 days a week)")
    print("3 being moderately active (moderate exercise 3-5 days a week)")
    print("4 being very active (hard exercise 6-7 days a week)")
    print("5 being super active (very hard exercise and a physical job)")
    print("Exercise would be 15 to 30 minutes of having an elevated heart rate.")
    print("Hard exercise would be 2 plus hours of elevated heart rate.")
    daily_calorie_requirement = get_daily_calorie_requirement()
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful to show us the error you're facing, it's hard to tell what the issue could be since the code isn't working either. If you have a traceback, that would be useful in solving this Question.

Assigning simply occurs when there is a variable on the left hand side of an `=`. When calling a method such as `get_bmr()` what ever is `return`'ed by this function will be assigned.

Your code could be failing since you're trying to get `gender` but this isn't defined in under function `main`. You can replace the `if gender "M" elif "F"` with simply the following. (Since you call all this in `get_bmr`)

```py
bmr = get_bmr()
```

If you're wanting to pass `bmr` into the next function would creating an argument for `get_daily_calorie_requirement` resolve the issue?

```py
def get_daily_calorie_requirement(bmr):
    dcr_5 = 1.9
    return int(bmr * dcr_5)


def main():
    bmr = get_bmr()

    daily_calorie_requirement = get_daily_calorie_requirement(bmr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want to simplify it you could move some of the parameters into arguments:

```py
def get_bmr(gender, age, height, weight):
    """ Calculate BMR using the following formula:

    bmr = weight_const*weight ... etc.
    """
    gender_coef = 5 if gender == "M" else -161

    return int((4.536 * weight) + (15.88 * height) - (5 * age) + 5)


gender = input("What is your gender: M or F?")
while gender not in ["M", "F"]:
    print("Please try again, accepted values: M/F")
    gender = input("What is your gender: M or F?")

age = int(input("What is your age?"))
height = int(input("What is your height in inches?"))
weight = int(input("What is your weight in pounds?"))

bmr = get_bmr(gender, age, height, weight)
```

Few things that can be tricky, naming variables the same as your functions, or simply forgetting to `return` in a function.

Comment: Thank you so much my problem was trying to pass bmr into the next argument which was where I was stuck. I put it in as the argument for  daily_calorie_requirement = get_daily_calorie_requirement(bmr) and it worked. Sorry I was a little vague and didn't post the error but you were able to answer my question.

Comment: @Mhurtad14 don't forget to accept the answer if it helped solving your question ^_^